# Unwanted (meta?) data in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, nested-forms

I have two models (questions and answers) that slightly follow the popular [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :content
end
```

The answers are built (for the purposes of my application) inside the *edit* method of my question_controller.rb:

```
2.times do
    @question.answers.build
end
```

and rendered inside the edit view - edit.html.haml as:

```
= f.fields_for :answers do |builder|
    = render "answer_fields", :f => builder
```

The problem appears when I want to show the answers. Inside show.html.haml, I do:

```
= for answer in @question.answers
  = answer.content
```

The answer contents are shown, but I also get this (unwanted) HTML code:

```
  [#&lt;Answer id: 11, question_id: 22, content: &quot;100&quot;, created_at: &quot;2012-04-02 08:34:50&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2012-04-02 08:34:50&quot;&gt;,]
```

Any thoughts on how to remove this? I can't find any reason for the presence of this additional data.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
= for answer in @question.answers
  = answer.content
```

With

```
- for answer in @question.answers
  = answer.content
```

(The first version prints out the content of @question.answers, the second just runs the loop)

See the [haml documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_evaluation) for inserting ruby vs running ruby